# Call subprocess "ls -l folder | wc -l" in python can't be done

Tags: python, subprocess, call

I want to run this command using call subprocess

```
ls -l folder | wc -l
```

My code in Python file is here:

```
subprocess.call(["ls","-l","folder","|","wc","-l"])
```

I got an error message like this:

```
ls: cannot access |: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access wc: No such file or directory
```

It's like command `|wc` can't be read by call subprocess.

How can i fix it?

Comment: Pipes are shell thing. The shell would fork two subprocess, and pipe stdout of 1st subprocess into stdin of 2nd one. You would need to implement that logic yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try out the shell option using a string as first parameter:

```
subprocess.call("ls -l folder | wc -l",shell=True)
```

Although this work, note that using `shell=True` is not recommended since it can introduce a security issue through [shell injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection#Shell_injection).

Comment: Thank you its working well :)

Comment: It's not returning expected result, it's just that error has gone

Comment: Thank you AlokThakur. The first parameter must be a string. Should be working now.

Comment: Hi @Rembulan if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a command pipeline by connecting one process's `stdout` with another's `stdin`. In your example, errors and the final output are written to the screen, so I didn't try to redirect them. This is generally preferable to something like `communicate` because instead of waiting for one program to complete before starting another (and encouring the expense of moving the data into the parent) they run in parallel.

```
import subprocess

p1 = subprocess.Popen(["ls","-l"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(["wc","-l"], stdin=p1.stdout)
# close pipe in parent, its still open in children
p1.stdout.close()
p2.wait()
p1.wait()
```

Comment: thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to implement the piping logic yourself to make it work properly.

```
def piped_call(prog1, prog2):
  out, err = subprocess.call(prog1).communicate()
  if err:
    print(err)
    return None
  else:
    return subprocess.call(prog2).communicate(out)
```

Comment: thank you for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using subprocess.PIPE, assuming you wanted to avoid using `subprocess.call(..., shell=True)`.

```
import subprocess

# Run 'ls', sending output to a PIPE (shell equiv.: ls -l | ... )
ls = subprocess.Popen('ls -l folder'.split(),
                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# Read output from 'ls' as input to 'wc' (shell equiv.: ... | wc -l)
wc = subprocess.Popen('wc -l'.split(), 
                      stdin=ls.stdout, 
                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# Trap stdout and stderr from 'wc'
out, err = wc.communicate()

if err:
    print(err.strip())

if out:
    print(out.strip())
```

For Python 3 keep in mind the `communicate()` method used here will return a `byte` object instead of a string. :

In this case you will need to convert the output to a string using `decode()`:

```
if err:
    print(err.strip().decode())
if out:
    print(out.strip().decode())
```

Comment: thank you, still learning about subprocess :)